# cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.in': error 0x7e

Tags: python, r, django, runtime-error

I am getting a exception in thread django-main-thread error. when referencing ffi.dlopen('C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin'). The error is "cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.in': error 0x7e" I don't understand why it changes "bin" to "in". any help would be appreciated. I am new to Django so it could be a super simple problem.

Thanks

[image: code segment of error]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! Please provide more information about your problem? Show us the code where the error is, so that people will have more stuff to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Even python has a thing about backslashes, you need to be aware of it.

```py
In [1]: 'c:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin'
Out[1]: 'c:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.0\x08in'
```

(Note the `\x08in` instead of the expected `\\bin`.)

This is why `bin` is changed to `in`. Python supports raw-strings, perhaps you should try that instead:

```py
In [2]: r'c:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin'
Out[2]: 'c:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.0\\bin'
```